# How to select in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to click this button in a website using selenium but I am not sure how to select it.

```
<a data-gfm-analytics-element="btn_showmore_browse" data-area="norma_category" class="button hollow expanded-mobile js-load-more-results" href="#" style="display: inline-block;">Show More</a>
```

I used this code to do it but it returns NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element

```
btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'button hollow expanded-mobile js-load-more-results')
```

Answer (score 1):

`button hollow expanded-mobile js-load-more-results` are actually 4 class names while `By.CLASS_NAME` receives single class name value. You can use CSS Selector or Xpath with multiple class names

```py
btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a.button.hollow.expanded-mobile.js-load-more-results')
```

Also `btn_showmore_browse` seems to be unique value, so possibly this will work too:

```py
btn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[data-gfm-analytics-element="btn_showmore_browse"]')
```

There are more possible options